# .NET CORE 3.1 - [HttpPost] - The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: c#, json

I try to have **more than one parameter** in a **POST** from angular 9 to a .NET API controller

I get the error **The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken**

when sending my request, passing these arguments to my http post from **angular 9**

from:

```
return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + 'api/Partners/',partner : partner);
```

to

```
return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + 'api/Partners/',{partner : partner,manager : manager});
```

using the following code for the .NET controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> PostPartner([FromBody] JObject body)
{
    Partner partner = body["partner"].ToObject<Partner>();
    User manager = body["manager"].ToObject<User>();
    ...
```

JObject beeing from using **Newtonsoft.Json.Linq**

I know I can use System.text.json but I just don't find any example that fits my post function signature

any help appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, you should be able to use a model class which should contain both the `Partner` and the `User` properties like:

```
public class PostPartnerModel
{
    public Partner Partner { get; set; }
    public User Manager { get; set; }
}
```

and have your action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> PostPartner([FromBody] PostPartnerModel model)
{
  Partner partner = model.Partner;
  User manager = model.Manager;
  ...
```